# apply to four universities vs apply for college?

Tags: word-usage

I **applied to four universities** and was accepted by all of them. (http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/apply)
Many high school students have begun **applying for college**. 
(http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/apply)

The two sentences are cited from Webster dictionary and Longman dictionary respectively. I am confused with which preposition (to or for) should I use if I want to say "to request admission to a university". I think "to" is a proper preposition. Why does the second sentence use "to"?

Answer (score 1):

In:

> I **applied to** four universities and was accepted by all of them.

you are applying to a place, so you would use *to*.

But in:

> Many high school students have begun **applying for** college.

*college* as used here is the reason you are applying, so here you would use *for*.

See the definition of [***apply***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/apply) sense 5:

> to make a formal request (***to*** someone ***for*** something)

Answer (score -1):

We apply to a school, college, or a university for admission. The use of the preposition "for" in the sentence "Many high school students have begun applying for college" is grammatically incorrect; it should be "........applying to college".